# Postgres - Group by without having to aggregate?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

This is hard to explain, but say I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM "late_fee_tiers"
```

And it returns this:

[image]

I have a validation in code set up to prevent duplicate `days` from being saved (notice there are 2 rows of `days = 2`).

I want my query to double-check there are only unique rows of `day`, and if there are multiple, select the first one (so it should return 3 rows with 2,3,5).

My first thought is to use `GROUP BY` day, while selecting a `MIN("id")`.

The problem is, I don't understand SQL enough, because it forces me to add different aggregator functions to every single column... but what if I don't want to do that? I want THAT row to be "chosen" according to the single aggregator function I define, I don't need multiple aggregators creating some weird hybrid row. I just want the MIN() function to choose that 1 row and fill in all the rest of the values for that row.

What function do I use to do this, or how would I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Which out of the two rows do you want to select?

Comment: I want to select the `MIN("id")`, so the final ID's are: `82, 84, 85`

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
select distinct on (day) *
from "late_fee_tiers"
order by day, id;
```

> Why `day` is also required in the `order by`:

From the official documentation:

> The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY
>   expression(s). The ORDER BY clause will normally contain additional
>   expression(s) that determine the desired precedence of rows within
>   each DISTINCT ON group.

Comment: Hmm I see, can you explain why it needs to order by `day, id` instead of `id`?

Comment: @Tallboy - Added some explanation and also link to documentation .

Comment: Hmm... I follow about 85%. Thank you

Comment: This didn't work btw, I forgot to mention that it needs to be "scoped" to `late_schedule_id` (so 1 unique day per `late_schedule_id`. How would I go about doing that?